# VSCode - Enclose expression in a function call, much like IntelliJ's .arg

Tags: visual-studio-code

- Assume we've got `Math.random() * 5|`, | being the caret's position.
- I'd like it to convert to `someFunc(Math.random() * 5)` as quickly as possible. In Webstorm and other JetBrains IDE's, I'd simply write `.arg` at the end of an expression, press tab, and it'd get automatically enclosed in braces, and the caret would be placed before them.

Does VSC offer such a functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I use following shortcuts to quicly enclose selected text in braces:

```
{"key":       "shift+9", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "$0($TM_SELECTED_TEXT)"  }, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key":       "shift+0", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet":   "($TM_SELECTED_TEXT)$0"}, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key": "alt+` shift+[", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "$0{$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}"  }, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key": "alt+` shift+]", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet":   "{$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$0"}, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key":       "["      , "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "$0[$TM_SELECTED_TEXT]"  }, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key":       "]"      , "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet":   "[$TM_SELECTED_TEXT]$0"}, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key":       "shift+,", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "$0<$TM_SELECTED_TEXT>"  }, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key":       "shift+.", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet":   "<$TM_SELECTED_TEXT>$0"}, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},

{"key": "alt+` shift+9", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "$0(\n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n)"  }, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key": "alt+` shift+0", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet":   "(\n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n)$0"}, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key":       "shift+[", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "$0{\n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n}"  }, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key":       "shift+]", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet":   "{\n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n}$0"}, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key": "alt+` ["      , "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "$0[\n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n]"  }, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key": "alt+` ]"      , "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet":   "[\n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n]$0"}, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key": "alt+` shift+,", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "$0<\n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n>"  }, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
{"key": "alt+` shift+.", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet":   "<\n\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n>$0"}, "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"},
```

Out of those, only the first one is useful in your case.

First, you need to select the expression, either with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>◀</kbd><kbd>◀</kbd>...<kbd>◀</kbd>, or, if your language support extension is clever enough, with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd>...<kbd>▶</kbd> (aka `editor.action.smartSelect.expand`).

Then you press <kbd>(</kbd> (aka <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>), and get `|(Math.random() * 5)`, where `|` is the caret. Then you type the function name.